# How to wrap every N elements in parent div in ERB (Rails)?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

My members index page is simply a list of members, but I'd like every 3 members to be wrapped in a containing div (that will act like a row). So rather than:

```
<div class="member"></div>
<div class="member"></div>
<div class="member"></div>
<div class="member"></div>
<div class="member"></div>
```

I need the markup to be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
</div>
```

I do have a solution, but I'm not happy with it. I have actually seen a better way to do it in ERB before, but can't find it again.

My current code:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @members.each do |member| %>
    <div class="member"><%=member.name%></div>
    <%= cycle("", "", "</div><div class=\"row\">".html_safe) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about this:

```
<% @members.each_slice(3) do |slice| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% slice.each do |member| %>
      <div class="member">
      ...your markup here
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can also replace the each_slice(3) with in_groups_of(3,false)

Comment: `in_groups_of ` didnt work for me. this answer `each_slice` saved my time.

Answer (score 3):

I found the method I was looking for. It's basically identical to `each_slice()` posted by @HargrimmTheBleak, but has a more friendly name:

[`in_groups_of()`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html#M000833)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a great chance to use a modulus

```
<div class="row">
<% for(i=1, i<=@members.size, i++ %>
    <% if i%4 == 0 %>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
    <% end %>
    <div class="member"><%=@members[i-1]%></div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: This is even more complex than the cycle() helper. I'm looking for something simpler.